# CKEditor plugins not working/appearing

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have followed the documentation and added two plugins:

- enhanced image (image2)
- enhanced color button

but neither appears in my toolbar. I have added all the dependencies.

Here's my `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
    { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
    { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
    { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
    { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
    { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
    { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
    { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
];

config.height = 500;        // 500 pixels.

/*config.removePlugins = 'colorbutton';*/

config.extraPlugins = 'button', 'toolbar', 'notification', 'clipboard', 'lineutils', 'dialogui', 'dialog', 'widgetselection', 'widget', 'image2', 'panel', 'floatpanel', 'panelbutton', 'enhancedcolorbutton';

config.removeButtons = 'NewPage,Source,Scayt,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Outdent,Indent,Blockquote,CreateDiv,BidiLtr,BidiRtl,Language,Anchor,Flash,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe,BGColor,Maximize,ShowBlocks';
};
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please see:https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins

The list of plugins should be entered as a single string of comma separated values:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'button,toolbar,notification,clipboard,lineutils,dialogui,dialog,widgetselection,widget,image2,panel,floatpanel,panelbutton,enhancedcolorbutton';
```

**NOTE:** plugins like `button`,`toolbar`,`dialog` and `dialogui`, should be available in any preset so unless you are having some very customized package, there should be no need to add them with `extraPlugins` setting.  They should already be in the package.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the delay, I have been away from this for a while.  I have changed the config.js but the extra plugins are not showing in my panel; should they be in there automatically or do I have to change something?

Comment: From the attached plugins you will only see image2 and maybe enhancedcolorbutton (sorry I don't know this one) in the toolbar. The rest of those extra plugins have no toolbar button. Could you click on image button and check if you can see its new dialog (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2 - you can check how dialog looks like on one of screen-shots). If you can't see it, please open dev-tools and tell me if you are getting any errors in console.

Comment: The image2 is the main one for me, I can manage without the colour one. 

I get [violation] Avoid using document.write.  ckeditor.js:557  and
[violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 137ms  ckeditor.js:250

Comment: Messages you get look like warnings at best but not errors. Could you perhaps start over try using the online builder this time - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder? Please select predefined package there and add image2 plugin to it (all required plugins will be auto-added). Next, please try using in your `config.js` only this setting `config.extraPlugins = 'image2,enhancedcolorbutton';`  and see if this is working for you.